# How can connect VS2017 and Mac agent which are both on different machine for Xamrin IOS development?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have installed VS2017 on a windows machine and Xamarin.ios on other MAC machines.
Is it possible to connect VS2017 from windows machin to Mac agent of MAC machine.

Comment: Yes.  This scenario is exactly why the Mac build agent exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can connect from visual studio to the mac agent as long as the 2 machine are on the same network. You can refer to [HERE](https://lowleetak.wordpress.com/2017/07/01/setup-and-install-xamarin-for-visual-studio-2015-xamarin-mac-agent/) for the guide to setup the connection. It is for VS2015 but should be the same for VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jason said, it is supported by Visual Studio.

You can refer to this Xamarin official documentation on how to connect them:

> This guide explains the features provided Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio and how the connection to the Mac build host is made.

- [Connecting to the Mac](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/)

If you are using Visual Studio Enterprise, you can enable "Remote Simulator to Windows" feature. Then iOS simulator will be showed directly on the PC and you don't need to move to the Mac when you debug apps. Refer to the following link for more details:

- [Remoted iOS Simulator (for Windows)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/)